# How to get NReco.PdfGenerator to honour `column-count` css property

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, html2pdf, nreco

I've got a web page enrolment form that we need to email to our customers.  The form has been divided into 2 columns using the `column-count` css property.
Unfortunately, when *NReco.PdfGenerator* generates the Pdf, these columns are rendered as a single column, breaking the flow of the form.

As an example, using the [Online Pdf Generator](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx) on the *NReco* web page and the [example for `column-count` from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_column-rule) (yes, I know!), we can see only a single column generated.

Does anyone have any idea how to get *NReco.PdfGenerator* to honour the `column-count` property, or of another library that can successfully transform some large (9 page) web forms?

**Update**

Looks like this is an issue with the underlying [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) library (which has now been archived)

Anyone know of a fork of this that is being updated?

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed wkhtmltopdf is based on QtWebKit 4.8 which is rather old rendering engine and it doesn't support many modern CSS3 things including "column-count".

You may try this workaround to achieve result that is similar to "column-count": https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1872 (not a 100% replacement as it works only for content that fits a single page). Another option can be usage of js plugin that splits content on 'columns' like this one: https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin

Finally, you can consider to use modern headless-Chrome based way to convert HTML pages to PDFs: https://gotenberg.dev/ (its deployment is not so simple as wkhtmltopdf -- it requires a separate docker container to run) and use one of existing .NET clients to access this web API from C# code. If you like NReco.PdfGenerator API simplicity technically it is possible to add 'HtmlToPdfConverter' implementation that will use gotenberg API instead of wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Thank you for the many suggestions.  I'll look into them all.